# can't create Application.java file inside java folder of my app

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, notifications

I am working on a flutter app on vscode and trying to add device to device notifications functionality to my app.
I followed a video guide- [**Device to Device Notification | FCM | Firebase and Flutter**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-v5tS0HhCg&t=519s&ab_channel=DhruvilXcode) ,
but I don't get any notifications. So I think it's because of an error I have when I create Application.java file in android/app/main/java/. The error was `Application.java is not on the classpath of project app. Only syntax errors are reported.` I tried to open vscode android file in android studio to create Application.java file, but somehow vscode said `can't find android studio`.

1. How do I create Application.java file without any error?
2. How do I make device-to-device notifications work if I can't create Application.java file properly?

screenshots;

1. my app folder structure  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTXil.png
2. my `Application.java`file location  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeJDs.png
3. error in `Application.java` https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TCT2.png

Comment: Does the project work well in VS Code, then opening it in Android Studio throw error?

Comment: Hi, Molly. In Vscode, the error is thrown, and notification doesn't work. In Android studio, Application.java file shows many red lines under many parts of the code, and doesn't work either. I followed exactly the video, but only difference is that I have the error and my notification doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the project folder structure and error in VS Code by screenshots?Please be attention to protect your own privacy. In another hand, i'll follow the tutorial you provided and try to reproduce your question.

Comment: I posted 3 screenshots. If you need anything else, please let me know.

Comment: one more difference between video and me is that I can't open Android Studio when I click 'open in Android Studio' button shown after right-clicking android folder in file explorer like the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this github issue: [not on the classpath of project app, only syntax errors are reported](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1390).

The production group developer replied `android is not supported by VSCode-Java` and explained:

> Android uses special Gradle plugins to compute the project classpath, that are not supported in Buildship, the underlying Gradle Integration plugin we delegate Gradle support to.

> Currently, there is no ideal solution for that but you can try the Lightweight mode by settingjava.server.launchMode to LightWeight. You will be able to use a subset of features like Go to Definition of the types inside your local source and JDK. But there are also limitations, you won't be able to navigate to the types in Android SDK, and you won't be able to build and debug.